# How to change screen on double tap

Tags: iphone, touch-event

I have successfully made a double tap action using `- (void) touchesEnded` but I would like to make a double tap event that switches to another view like it would if you pushed a button . How would I do this?

Comment: The same way you would inside of the `IBAction` that a button would trigger

Comment: Can i do this through IB or do i need to do it in code?

Comment: through code, can you post your `IBAction` method including `-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender{//switch view code}`?  And the `touchesEnded` code wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You can also implement through gesture recognizer Tap-gesture with two taps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this in code, I think.  You can create the segue in interface builder, give it an identifier, and then call performSegueWithIdentifier when you catch the double-touch event.

Answer (score 0):

Using a gesture will be useful and simple. Simply set the count of Touches & you are done.